# Collecting spatial data via Survey123 in ArcGIS - Can you update existing feature information?

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I am putting together a form in Survey 123 for field data collection. I have a shapefile of parking lots, and I would love for someone to be able to click on a location on the map and be able to edit a field after counting how many parking spots are in that location. Is this possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this its not possible. I have been trying to figure it out for a while now and it seems like its only possible with QField or mergin maps.